# uploading file in php ci framework neither show errors nor show result

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had seen many videos and took reference from CI user guide but became unable to find out error.When file is submitted from the form,it sends program flow the the uploadImage() method below.Please help me with the way.
Thank you

My code:

```
     public function uploadImage()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './files/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload())
        {
        $this->load->view('upload');
        }
        else
        {
        $this->upload->display_errors();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to do as plz see below may help..

```
  public function uploadImage()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './files/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

//load upload class library
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    //$this->upload->do_upload('filename') will upload selected file to destiny folder
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
    {
        // case - failure
        $upload_error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('edit', $upload_error);
    }
    else
    {
        // case - success
        //callback  returns an array of data related to the uploaded file like the file name, path, size etc


    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
$data['success_msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your file <strong>' .$upload_data['file_name']. '</strong> was successfully uploaded!</div>';
             //$this->load->view('edit_profile', $data);


        redirect(base_url("Display_somepage/index"));
        }
```

//this below may be helpful to for debugging

```
echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
```

Comment: I am trying to upload a file of range in config array,it neither shows error nor file is uploaded.

Comment: @Sajal if you have to specify range of file then have to add   $config['max_size']    = '78000'; //size allowed to display errors use die(var_dump()) or print_r($config); it will give array with all result displayed plz post value of print_r($config) for more information after trying

Comment: @Sajal you are also loading view before displaying errors that's why it don't show errors see my code above for case failure in if condidtion

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a syntax error, notice the arrow.

```
public function uploadImage()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './files/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload('YOUR_FILE_INPUT_NAME'))  <=========== HERE
    {
     $this->load->view('upload');
    }
    else
    {
     $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
}
```

Basically, you are telling it to load the view when the uploading succeed, else show errors if the operation fails not the opposite.

Comment: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\system\libraries\Upload.php on line 884